Old movie about Kids travelling with babysitter in order to stop their father's wedding
This is what I remember from the movie:
Kids are left with a babysitter/housekeeper while father goes to another place.
Kids travel with said baby/house-sitter in order to stop their father's wedding.
One of the phrases I remember was in a barn one of the kids meets a girl and the babysitter hears them say "I've never reached this far before." She goes to see what was happening and sees they were actually playing a video-game.
It ends at night with a remote controlled car attached to a camera taping the father kissing the babysitter.

Can you tell us anything else? Was it in color? English? Was it an American film? How old is it, etc.

It is in color. American. They spoke in english. Should be late 80's or early 90's.

Au Pair (1999) watched on "Family Channel." Kids like to prank babysitter, but then like babysitter. Romance between single father and babysitter ensue. Kids stop the father's evil fiance's plans. Babysitter and father get together and the kids are happy.

That was the movie. Much appreciated :)

This film sounds kind of like On Our Own (1988):

Four children set out on their own after their mother's death to avoid being separated by foster care. Trying to find their Uncle Jack, they encounter adventure and danger. Before the story's touching yet humorous conclusion, they make some serious mistakes... and learn some important lessons. - imdb

In this case, the four kids are searching for their Uncle Jack hoping to find ties to their father. Ultimately it is revealed that their father is prison and Jack isn't their real uncle, that doesn't stop him from adopting them in the end. 

This story is told by a grandmother on the other end of the phone while baking a cake (which later turns out to be a wedding cake for her daughter and Uncle Jack). - tvtropes

Ultimately this woman who was watching the kids Petty ends up marrying Jack. Which might be the "babysitter kissing the dad" thing you remember.  




Wasn't "On Our Own". But thx anyway :)
